# JavaScript and PHP code not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have simple code with html, JavaScript and PHP. I am trying to pass a variable from HTML to PHP through ajax.

A text box appears on screen with button, user inputs in the text field and clicks the button. The field text should appear before the field. But in my case, nothing happens when clicking the button. I am posting my code below. These are the three files I have made:

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en">
   <body>
      <input id="name" type="text" /> <input id="button" type="button" value="Load" /> 
      <div id="content"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script> 
   </body>
</html>
```

**ajax.js**

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
    document.write("this is javascript");
    var name = $('#name').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'page.php',
        data: name,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**page.php**

```php
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['name'])) {
        echo "lllllllllllllllll";
        echo $name=$_GET['name'];
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: i am trying to add code but unable to resolve code indent issues...trying to resolve that

Comment: file:index.html....................................
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <body>
         <input id="name" type="text" />
         <input id="button" type="button" value="Load" />
         <div id="content"></div>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: file:ajax.js...........................................
       $('#button').click(function() 
       {
         document.write("this is  javascript");
         var name=$('#name').val();
          $.ajax({
            url:'page.php',
            data: name,
            success:function(data){
         $('#content').html(data);
            }
                });
         });

Comment: file:page.php.......................................
   <?php
        if(isset($_GET['name']))
        {
         echo"lllllllllllllllll";
         echo $name=$_GET['name'];
        } 
    ?>

Comment: Above are the codes of the three files.

Comment: Please edit the question, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51803141/edit, so the code is readable.

Comment: Edit your post and add the code. The comment section is to clarify doubts.

Comment: You'll also need to add more details. Open the developer console and add information about what actually happens when the button is pressed. The `data` value being sent seems off to me.

Comment: lose the `document.write("this is javascript");` - it serves no purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add CDN as mentioned above. Also make sure you load the jquery CDN or jquery.lib.js before including external js file, ajax.js in index.html.

There is an issue in your $.ajax code:

$.ajax({
    url: 'page.php',
    **data: name,**
    success: function(data) {
        $('#content').html(data);
    }
});
change this to:

$.ajax(
    {
       type:'GET',
       url: 'page.php',
       data:"name=test"
    },
    success: function(data) {
       $('#content').html(data);
    }
);

Comment: I have done that. Now that error is resolved. but it is not loading php file. it gives error in console that : Failed to load http://localhost/test/page.php: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: i have given URL like this in js file : url:'http://localhost/test/page.php',     is this has issue ?

Comment: How does a CDN resolve any issue? It just serves the content from a different resource.

Comment: please check I have updated my answer, there is a problem with our ajax code. You must mentioned the type of method (GET/POST). Since you are using GET i have updated code accordingly. And there was a problem in sending the params, this has to be a key/value pari basis.

Comment: please check I have updated my answer, there is a problem with our ajax code. You must mentioned the type of method (GET/POST). Since you are using GET i have updated code accordingly. And there was a problem in sending the params, this has to be a key/value pari basis.

Comment: @RizwanKhan awesome. Your corrections worked. It's working fine now. Huge round of applause for you :) Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

only add before axaj.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your javascript ajax: `type : 'GET'`.
In your php code :

```
$name=$_GET['name']; 
echo $name;
```